# How to retrieve related name of Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given models like:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    writer=models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

How would you do:

```
>>> get_related_name(Author, Article)
'article_set'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`_meta` API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/).

```
for field in Author._meta.get_fields():
    if field.related_model == Article
        print(field.related_name)
```

Comment: Works great, you just need a colon after Article.

Answer (score 0):

Each [model's `_meta` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/) stores information “about” the model, that is not fields or methods. This includes the `related_name` of ForeignKey relationships.

```python
related_name = None
for field in Author._meta.get_fields():
    if field.related_model is Article:
        related_name = field.related_name
        break
```